# Django inline for model inheritance target

Tags: django, inheritance, django-admin, inline

I am trying to solve problem related to model inheritance in Django. I have four relevant models: `Order`, `OrderItem` which has ForeignKey to `Order` and then there is `Orderable` model which is model inheritance superclass to children models like `Fee`, `RentedProduct` etc. In python, it goes like this (posting only relevant parts):

```
class Orderable(models.Model):
    real_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, editable=False)  

    objects = OrderableManager()

    available_types = []

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Saves instance and stores information about concrete class.
        """
        self.real_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(self))
        super(Orderable, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def cast(self):
        """
        Casts instance to the most concrete class in inheritance hierarchy possible.
        """
        return self.real_content_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.pk) 

    @staticmethod
    def register_type(type):
        Orderable.available_types.append(type)

    @staticmethod
    def get_types():
        return Orderable.available_types

class RentedProduct(Orderable):
    """
    Represent a product which is rented to be part of an order
    """
    start_at = models.ForeignKey(Storage, related_name='starting_products',
        verbose_name=_('Start at'))
    real_start_at = models.ForeignKey(Storage, null=True,
        related_name='real_starting_products', verbose_name=_('Real start at'))
    finish_at = models.ForeignKey(Storage, related_name='finishing_products',
        verbose_name=_('Finish at'))
    real_finish_at = models.ForeignKey(Storage, null=True,
        related_name='real_finishing_products', verbose_name=_('Real finish at'))

    target = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name=_('Product'))

Orderable.register_type(RentedProduct)

class OrderItem(BaseItem):
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, 
        verbose_name=_('Unit price'))
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_('Count'))
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', related_name='items',
        verbose_name=_('Order'))
    discounts = models.ManyToManyField(DiscountDescription,
        related_name='order_items', through=OrderItemDiscounts, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Discounts'))

    target = models.ForeignKey(Orderable, related_name='ordered_items',
        verbose_name=_('Target'))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('order', 'target')
```

I would like to have an inline tied to Order model to enable editing OrderItems. Problem is, that the target field in OrderItem points to Orderable (not the concrete class which one can get by calling Orderable's `cast` method) and the form in inline is therefore not complete.

Does anyone have an idea, how to create at least a bit user-friendly interface for this? Can it be solved by Django admin inlines only, or you would suggest creating special user interface?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm looking for a solid answer to this very thing, but you should check out FeinCMS. They are doing this quite well.

See, for example, the FeinCMS [inline editor](https://github.com/matthiask/feincms/blob/master/feincms/admin/item_editor.py). I need to figure out how to adapt this to my code.

Comment: Hi, since nobody seemed to have answer for this before you, I personally chose the way through the special interface. Trying to forge the thing by inlines was way too difficult for what I needed to accomplish. Will look on FeinCMS solution though. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try inherit OrderItemInlineAdmin's Form a define your own Form there. But fingers crossed for that.